# Custom attribute custom_attribute to quote & order table save from controller

Tags: magento-1.9

I have added one Custom attribute `custom_attribute` to quote & order table I am sending a response to my controller I want to save the response in my `custom_attribute` to `sales_flat_quote` & `sales_flat_order` table
can someone please help me how to achieve this

```
  $response = $this->getRequest()->getParam('data'); // i am getting response here in my controller 

      $quoteModelInstance = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $customerModelInstance = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
        $order->setQuote($quoteModelInstance);
        $order->setCustomAttribute($response);
        try {
            $order->save();

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            Mage::logException($e);
        }
```

Comment: can you please add your code for addition clarification?

Comment: @vino Updated  s

Comment: you missed $ for response variable.

Comment: Did you try $order->setData( 'custom_attribute',$response );

Comment: Please confirm the table names sales_flat_quote (or) sales_flat_quote_item   ?

Comment: @Nagaraju sales_flat_quote

Comment: @vino yes i tried getting  [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 1228ms] in console log

Comment: Enable developer mode and check the error

Answer (score 2):

I found another very easy solution for this please follow the steps below:

**Step 1:** 
in your controller action please save the custom attribute value as shown below

**Note:-** You should create a column for saving the value in **sales_flat_quote** table
 **Ex: custom_attribute** is the name of the column i have created

```
public function customAction(){

  $productPayDetails=$this->getRequest()->getPost();//get post values

  $myValue = 2; 

  Mage::getSingleton("checkout/cart")->getQuote()->setCustomAttribute($myValue)->save();

   (or)

  Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getQuote()->setCustomAttribute($myValue)->save();

}
```

**Step 2:** Create a column in the name of **custom_attribute** in **sales_flat_order** table

**Step 3:**  now keep the below code in between **global** tag from **config.xml** from your **custom module**

```
<global> 
<fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>
          <custom_attribute>
            <to_order>*</to_order>
           </custom_attribute>
        </sales_convert_quote>
        <sales_convert_order>
            <custom_attribute>
                <to_quote>*</to_quote>
            </custom_attribute>            
        </sales_convert_order>
    </fieldsets>
  </global>
```

clear cache and session and create an order and check the database.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am showing you how to save the values in the **sales_flat_order** table using **checkout_submit_all_after** event and observer concept.

**Step-1:** From your custom controller set the value into session as shown below

> /app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/controllers/IndexController.php

```
public function customAction(){

  $productPayDetails=$this->getRequest()->getPost();//get post values
  //write your code here
  .
  .


    $myValue = 2;
    Mage::getSingleton("checkout/cart")->getQuote()->setCustomAttribute($myValue)->save();

    (or)    

  Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getQuote()->setCustomAttribute($myValue)->save();
  .
  .
  $testValue = 10; //Ex: Your attribute value
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCustomerPaymentTotal($testValue);
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCustomerPendingTotal($testValue);
}
```

**Screen shot:** http://prntscr.com/fxz7eu

**Step 2:** Now Configure an event in config.xml from your custom module

> /app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/et/config.xml

```
  <frontend>
      <events>
         <checkout_submit_all_after>
                <observers>
                    <checkout_submit_all_after>
                        <class>intermediatepage/observer</class>
                        <method>checkout_submit_all_after</method>
                    </checkout_submit_all_after>
                </observers>
         </checkout_submit_all_after>
      </events>
</frontend>
```

**Note:** Here i am taking an example with intermediatepage class name

Step 3: Now Create a column in the **sales_flat_order** for example as shown in the 
 screenshot http://prntscr.com/fxxqgt

**Step 4:**  create an observer file

> /app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Observer {

    public function checkout_submit_all_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
     {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $pendingtotal=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCustomerPendingTotal();
    $paymenttotal=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCustomerPaymentTotal();
    $order->setOrderPendingPayment($pendingtotal);
    $order->setOrderPaymentNow($paymenttotal);
    $order->save();

 //unset the session values
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCustomerPendingTotal('');
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCustomerPendingTotal('');

 }

}
```

**Step 5:** after done the changes in xml please remove cache and session and please try this in default magento from your custom module in locally.

Comment: where you are getting the current quote Order ?

Comment: Actually i have explained u point no 2 , this is for saving the custom  value in the order table just try this and get back with u r doubts thanks

Comment: hi@ magento12345 please check now i have updated the code now please check now u can save the data into sales_flat_quote & sales_flat_order tables